# MySQL - Calculate SUM(field) per year from UNION

Tags: mysql, sum, union

I have an SQL UNION command that from a large db (`deaths_all`), I get the the year (`etos` variable) and the deaths for that year (`sunoloThanatwn`) for 3 different scenarios, as stated in the union.

For every year, 3 rows are correctly returned. I want to calculate the sum of `sunoloThanatwn`, so that I have one SUM(`sunoloThanatwn`) per year and not 3 rows per year.

SQL UNION Query:

```
(
  SELECT etos, sunoloThanatwn
  FROM deaths_all
  WHERE field = "A"
  GROUP BY etos
)
UNION
(
  SELECT etos, sunoloThanatwn
  FROM deaths_all
  WHERE field = "B"
  GROUP BY etos
)
UNION
(
  SELECT etos, sunoloThanatwn
  FROM deaths_all
  WHERE field = "C"
  GROUP BY etos
)
ORDER BY etos
```

The query result is the following (I need a sum per year):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a single aggregation query:

```
SELECT etos, SUM(sunoloThanatwn) AS total
FROM deaths_all
WHERE field IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY etos;
```